# Calculating Total in excel with just % values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sales data:

[image: sales Data]

I would like to calculate the "Total" rowbut in my actual spreadsheet I do not have access to "LY".  It is also not possible to add this column in.  Is there a way to calculate the total YoY value of-33% just by knowing the -50% and +50% YoY values for each product?

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: **You** have to decide what you want for that column.  Perhaps a weighted average? If so, the formula is in the Excel HELP topic for `AVERAGE`

Comment: Sorry, I need an exact value.  Thanks for coment.

Comment: I don't understand. A weighted average would be an exact value. As would a value comparing the first year to the last year. Without you describing what you want or providing a desired result given the data that you have, I'm sorry I won't be able to advise you further.

Comment: I think it would be best if I rewrite the question which would hopefully help explain the end result.. Appreciate your assistance...

Comment: Afternoon Ron, many thanks for your feedback on my question.  I have amended and hoping this now makes more sense.  If you can offer support or even further assistance on the question that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate LY given the Amt and YoY.

```
LY = Amt/(1+YoY)
```

So, in your example, you can calculate your result with :

```
C6: =(SUMPRODUCT(B4:B5,1/(1+C4:C5))-B6)/SUMPRODUCT(B4:B5,1/(1+C4:C5))
```

[image]

Comment: I was going down the array formula and would not have got to sumproduct...  You sir have saved me a lot of headaches!  Appreciated.